# Fetch the image url from SQL Server database to display an image

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a column in my database that stores the url of the user's profile picture. In the home page' `page_load` event handler, I need to determine the image url, but I don't know how to do that using SQL commands.

From the images below, how can I give the query result to the image's `ImageUrl` property?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this post and hope this will help you: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-from-database-in-Image-control-without-using-Generic-Handler-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Server.mappath("~/profilepicture/profilepicture.jpg")

```
OdbcDataReader reader=new OdbcDataReader();
reader=command.executereader;
    Profilephotobutton.imageur=server.mappath(" & reader.item(profilepicture) & ");
```

hope this helps

Comment: its just a datareader you have to execute your sql command in a datareader then you have to get the value  ex: odbcdatareader=command.executereader;